# Python search through a text file using a Dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, iteration

I have a very large text file (11 million+ records), ";" delimited, three columns.  I have a Pandas dataframe (single column) with the values that I need to search through the text file.
The problem is that I am not able to load the large text file into memory.

I have nested for loops and that is taking a very long time.  Searching for each column value within each line of the text file.  This is what I have:

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

os.chdir('D:\\AllFiles\\Projects')
mainPath = os.getcwd()

inputFile = 'A.txt'
inputPath = os.path.join(mainPath, inputFile)
input_data = open(inputPath, 'r')

outputFile = 'A_A.csv'
outputPath = os.path.join(mainPath, outputFile)
output_data = open(outputPath,'w')


#  input file name and location
actFile = 'SingleColList.txt'
actPath = os.path.join(mainPath, actFile)

#   Read the cleaned data in a dataframe 
act_df = pd.read_csv(actPath,header=0)

with input_data as f:
    for num, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        for index, row in act_df.iterrows():
            if row['col1'] in line:
                output_data.write( line ) 

input_data.close()
output_data.close()

print('Done!')
```

Is there something faster that I can use?

Comment: Options for faster / memory efficient / lazy-loading libraries: dask, pyspark, koalas.  These packages may or may not still top out your memory.  Another common approach is to split / partition your dataset into multiple smaller files so they can be read into memory and processed individually (and potentially in parallel, which is basically what the libraries mentioned above aim to do).

Comment: read_csv('A.txt') won't allow you to read all 11 M records? you can also set a chunksize to iterate over. also, look into https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html. you may not have to iterate, but rather use regex??? s1.str.contains('house|dog', regex=True) you can take all your search words and create a string separated by a pipe. hard to say exactly is this would work for your use case

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples that might help

Set up a simple file called 'A.txt' as

```
a;b;c
cat;dog;mouse
mouse;moose;mice
apple;pie;good
no;its;not
what;is;this
three;word;sentences
great;good;best
stop;doing;this
or;doing;that
```

Create a search word list

```
mylist = ['ca', 'why', 'help', 'cat', 'is', 'three', 'best']
```

**Option 1**: read file and parse; then search by column. Don't think this is a good option, but shown for comparison purposes.

```
In [33]: df = pd.read_csv('A.txt', sep=';')
    ...: df[df['a'].str.contains('|'.join(mylist), regex=True)]
Out[33]:
       a     b          c
0    cat   dog      mouse
5  three  word  sentences
```

**Option 2**: read file, don't parse so it searches entire row

```
In [34]: df = pd.read_csv('A.txt', header=0)
    ...: df[df['a;b;c'].str.contains('|'.join(mylist), regex=True)]
Out[34]:
                  a;b;c
0         cat;dog;mouse
4          what;is;this
5  three;word;sentences
6       great;good;best
7       stop;doing;this
```

**Option 3**: use chunksize and use option 1 or 2 or whatever you need during each iteration

```
In [35]: iterator = pd.read_csv('A.txt', header=0, chunksize=2)
    ...: for i in iterator:
    ...:     print(i)
    ...:
              a;b;c
0     cat;dog;mouse
1  mouse;moose;mice
            a;b;c
2  apple;pie;good
3      no;its;not
                  a;b;c
4          what;is;this
5  three;word;sentences
             a;b;c
6  great;good;best
7  stop;doing;this
           a;b;c
8  or;doing;that
```